# Where can I find NetworkManager.RecursiveDelete() in JXTA;

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, java-me, jxta

I am searching for the method called  NetworkManager.RecursiveDelete(). Do you know where I can find it in JXTA 2.6?

I began to search for NetworkManager in JXTA but I can not find it. In JXTA 2.5 it was very easy to find the diffrent classes. I hope you have a piece of advice.

Answer (score 3):

This version of the jxse 2.6 jars at [kenai](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comkenaijxse-057/com/kenai/jxse/jxse/2.6/) has the `net.jxta.platform.NetworkManager` class with the methods you're looking for.

Is that the same one you're using?

Comment: I can find it here http://java.net/projects/jxta-jxse/sources/svn/content/tags/2.6/jxse/src/main/java/net/jxta/platform/NetworkManager.java?rev=1103


But not in my Netbeans.

Comment: @Alex: is it the same jar - wanna download it again?